# What is the "generated" attribute seen in some HTML tag used for?

Tags: html

I saw it used in a HTML label tag but I have a feeling that it can be used with most HTML tags. I can kinda guess what it means. But I am more curious about what's the benefit of using it. I tried to google for some reference about it but couldn't find any, so I come to you experts. Thanks.

Example:

```
<label for="first_name" generated="true" class="error">This field is required.</label>
```

Comment: I don't think that is HTML.  Perhaps it's XML?  In any case, the meaning of that attribute would be dependent on host environment and perhaps project.

Comment: I put this snippet in the W3's validator, and under every doctype that I tried (HTML 3.2, 4.01, XHTML, HTML5) it complained about the `generated` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, @Ken

Comment: @Ken, technically it's not a *valid* attribute. See my answer below for more information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use it as a hook for JavaScript and/or CSS.

For example...

#### CSS

```
label[generated=true] {
   color: #ccc;
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');

for (var i = 0, length = labels.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (labels[i].getAttribute('generated') === 'true') {
       // Do something.
    }
}
```

It is often used on JavaScript generated elements, such as the `label` elements created by the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation).

You could use jQuery to *clean up* generated elements with...

```
$('*[generated=true]').remove();
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. You've answered my curiosity precisely.

Answer (score 3):

This is a *custom data* or *user-defined* attribute. In your case it has been added to denote an element that was *generated* on the page after it loaded, probably by JavaScript.

It's common to see other such attributes in heavy UI/UX web applications. They typically serve as *hooks* between technologies - CSS, JavaScript, HTML, etc.

Note that such attributes do not validate. If you are using HTML5, you can prefix them with `data-` to get around this issue (i.e. `data-generated="true"`). Read more [about custom data attributes in HTML5](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/).

Comment: Thanks Jason. So, what's the benefit of using it? Or what's the caveat if it's not specified for some element that was added to the page after loading by JavaScript?

Comment: It can be helpful when you need to interact with such elements, like remove them per **alex's** answer. These attributes aren't reserved for JavaScript, they could be part of the initial page markup.