# Where is the 'generated' attributed allowed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-validate

I'm getting this error in IntelliJ:

> Attribute 'generated' is not allowed here

Where the html snippet is:

```
<label generated="true" ... >
```

Is `generated` a "real" HTML attribute? It is added by the [jquery-ui-validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) plugin, on the error fields if validation fails. Where is it allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

orignal answer at : [What is the "generated" attribute seen in some HTML tag used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769823/what-is-the-generated-attribute-seen-in-some-html-tag-used-for)

This is a *custom data* or *user-defined* attribute. In your case it has been added to denote an element that was *generated* on the page after it loaded, probably by JavaScript.

It's common to see other such attributes in heavy UI/UX web applications. They typically serve as *hooks* between technologies - CSS, JavaScript, HTML, etc.

Note that such attributes do not validate. If you are using HTML5, you can prefix them with `data-` to get around this issue (i.e. `data-generated="true"`). Read more [about custom data attributes in HTML5](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/).

Comment: Hmm. So jquery-ui-validation "should" move to using data-generated? I'm currently using plain "generated" to be compatible.