# MVC & jQuery Validate, different HTML output on localhost vs live

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor, unobtrusive-validation

A very simple example with something strange going on. Never noticed it before, but this is the first time I've looked.

Got myself a model with a field like:

```
[Display(Name = "Full Name")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your Full name")]
[RegularExpression(@"^((\b[a-zA-Z]{2,40}\b)\s*){2,}$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter your first and last name.")]
public string FullName { get; set; }
```

Razor view:

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FullName, new { placeholder = "Full Name", @Class = "form-control input-sm" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FullName)
</div>
```

When I submit an invalid form, I get an error message as I should... but the HTML is different on localhost than on the server.

Localhost gives me a span id="FullName-error" with some aria tags. Live server gives me a span for="FullName", without aria tags. The files on production are nothing more than a Publish and Upload.

My localhost generates the following (this is inspecting it in the chrome debug window):

```
<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control input-sm input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-regex="Please enter your first and last name." data-val-regex-pattern="^((\b[a-zA-Z]{2,40}\b)\s*){2,}$" data-val-required="Please enter your Full name" id="FullName" name="FullName" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" value="" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" aria-describedby="FullName-error">
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="FullName" data-valmsg-replace="true">
<span id="FullName-error" class="">Please enter your Full name</span>
</span>
</div>
```

The live server generates the following:

```
<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control input-sm input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-regex="Please enter your first and last name." data-val-regex-pattern="^((\b[a-zA-Z]{2,40}\b)\s*){2,}$" data-val-required="Please enter your Full name" id="FullName" name="FullName" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" value="">
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="FullName" data-valmsg-replace="true">
<span for="FullName" generated="true" class="">Please enter your Full name</span>
</span>
</div>
```

Anyone have any thoughts or can hint at what's going on?

Comment: Seems there is some update installed on Local that is not on server...

Comment: Pranav Singh - are you guessing that Local is the more up to date, could it be either Local or Server? Or are you sure Local is more up to date from the code I have provided? Many thanks.

Comment: I think version of jQueryValidate is problem, See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769823/what-is-the-generated-attribute-seen-in-some-html-tag-used-for

Comment: Well, I am an idiot... of course. You are correct Pranav. When I published the project, it compiled Bundles of Javascript... I took out reference to these bundles and now the HTML is the same on local and server. Thank you so much for the help. Would you like to post so I can mark as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems something is changed while publishing the web application.

I think version of `jQueryValidate` is problem, please refer [What is the "generated" attribute seen in some HTML tag used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769823/what-is-the-generated-attribute-seen-in-some-html-tag-used-for)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to speculate that the Live server you are using is different in some way compared to your localhost. The problem could be that the live server has a different version of a language you are using or does not include some packages that you think it should.

An example would be that applications that use FastCGI, a lot of servers have it, but not all tiers have it. So you would need to check to make sure that it is enabled in the settings or the version you want is there on whatever host you are using.

Comment: This is certainly what I'm looking at now... Although any differences in files must be outside of the application because the files are identical. Uploaded the website onto a 3rd machine for good measure, has the same behaviour as the server. All 3 machines running .net 4.5.2, all running the same app pool versions. Argh :) thanks for answer.

Comment: Are you using a framework like laravel or something else?  And what localhost are you using?(Apache maybe?)

Comment: Pranav Singh pointed me in the right direction. Turns out my Publish was creating script bundles that were different than my local version... I'm an idiot. Thanks for your help :)